# Adding sub pages in github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've set up a new page in GitHub, and it is already displaying the home page. How can I display the sub-pages? I used `react-router-dom` and `HashRouter` but still it is not working and redirects to 404 not found.

Home - https://pjv17.github.io/frontend-assessment/

Sub - https://pjv17.github.io/frontend-assessment/exercise-2

This is my script in index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#fa-assessment-e1")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js File

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Exercise1 from "./pages/Exercise1";
import Exercise2 from "./pages/Exercise2";

function PageTitle() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Frontend Assessment | Exercise 1";
  }, []);
}

function App() {
  PageTitle();
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Exercise1 />}></Route>
        <Route path="exercise-2" exact element={<Exercise2 />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create `404.html` with the exact same code as in `index.html`. It will catch everything that is not found and show the content.